# Using Vertex Paint to variate Linked Duplicates

Tags: weight-painting, linked-data

Is there any way how to variate vertex colors on linked duplicates (sharing the same mesh data)? I am pretty sure it is not possible as vertex color is a part of the mesh so only some vertex paint modifier could do that (which does not exist)... but maybe anyone have an idea of a workaround?

My goal is to duplicate one model of a tree over a terrain and colorize it to make it look little different. But I still want to keep it linked so I can modify the source mesh easily.

Comment: Guessing cycles. You can add a noise node and use it to mix in some colour variation. By connecting the texture coordinate nodes object output to the noise vector and choosing a different object, say the ground plane, the noise stays stationary as you move the object, so the same tree in different locations will vary in different places.

Comment: No, the moddel is supposed to be exported to a game engine that supports Vertex Colors (Richard Burns Rally game). It looks like I will have to join all duplicates and colorize it afterwards :-/ But thanks for suggestions.